# How to install Apache Ignite web-console modules in binary distribution

Tags: installation, ignite, binaries, web-console

I have installed [Apache Ignite-binaries](http://mirrors.wuchna.com/apachemirror//ignite/2.6.0/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin.zip) `apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0` .

As part of the Apache [Ignite-web-console-pre-requsite steps](https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/v2.6/docs/build-and-deploy#prerequisites)  : 
It mentioned

```
Download the following dependencies:

For backend:
cd $IGNITE_HOME/modules/web-console/backend
npm install --no-optional

For frontend:
cd $IGNITE_HOME/modules/web-console/frontend
npm install --no-optional
```

However when i go to `IGNITE_HOME` , i am unable to find the `modules` directory or 
`/modules/web-console/frontend`
`/modules/web-console/backend` directory.

Am I missing something as part of the ApacheIgnite-installation or web-console installation. 
Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the [*source* Ignite download](https://ignite.apache.org/download.cgi#sources) rather than the binary one.

Comment: Yes, binary distribution does not contain web console.